# My in-app-purchase app keeps crashing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Everything goes smoothly until I try to retrieve the SkuDetails.
I've done everything to the smallest detail that googles guide says, but still no luck.

My "thefullgame" product has been setup at Google Dev and it has been activated as well.

I've uploaded a version of my APK as the guide tells me to.. (it doesn't need to be in beta/alpha right?)

My simplified MainActivity code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MY_KEY";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
       public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
          if (!result.isSuccess()) {

            Gdx.app.log("..", "::Problem : " + result);

         }            

        List<String> additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
        additionalSkuList.add("thefullgame");

        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, mQueryFinishedListener);
       }
   });

}



QueryInventoryFinishedListener 
   mQueryFinishedListener = new QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
   public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)   
   {
      if (result.isFailure()) {

          Gdx.app.log("..", "error : " + result );

         return;
       }

      SkuDetails myDetails = inventory.getSkuDetails("thefullgame");

      String fullgamePrice = myDetails.getPrice(); // this is the line it crashes at (line 61)


   }
};
```

LOGCAT :

```
08-06 21:41:25.988: D/AndroidRuntime(11130): Shutting down VM
08-06 21:41:25.988: W/dalvikvm(11130): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41744da0)
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130): Process: com.blabla.blabla, PID: 11130
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130):    at com.blabla.blabla.MainActivity$2.onQueryInventoryFinished(MainActivity.java:61)
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130):    at    com.blabla.blabla.IabHelper$2$1.run(IabHelper.java:630)
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
08-06 21:41:25.988: E/AndroidRuntime(11130):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: So I am guessing myDetails is null? Is "thefullgame" a valid sku name that you have defined in your developer console?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad idea to have published the apk to (at least) alpha-- otherwise you tend to get an error about "*this version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play.  Check the help center for more information*."

Unfortunately, there are a **[ton](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=141&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Google%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&start=100)** of [bugs](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/list) in IABHelper-- most of them have to do with the async methods, but some of them are just [dumb](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/attachmentText?id=133&aid=1330000000&name=IabHelper.java.patch&token=ABZ6GAeLR_aHLX6BSr8PVZ0GFdUtjlhT_Q%3A1407362537735) and even fixes to bugs themselves [have introduced bugs](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=123).  (In the latter example, the fix to the fix accepted *today* took about 8 months to be accepted).

Luckily, most issues have been found and are discussed in the [issues queue](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/list).  You'll need to explore the list and perhaps solve them yourself.  Your issue looks similar to the one described [here](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=114).  I didn't look carefully, but something like this may help:

```
     int queryPurchases(com.blabla.blabla.MainActivity.util.Inventory inv, String itemType) throws JSONException, RemoteException {
+        if (mDisposed) return IABHELPER_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
+        checkNotDisposed();
+        checkSetupDone("queryPurchases");
         // Query purchases
```

(If you don't have mDisposed, you may not be using the most current source.  Also be sure you have the [fix posted today](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/detail?r=15946261ec9ae5f7c664d720f392f7787e3ee6c7).)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure where to place the code you answered with as I'm not trying to queryPurchases at this point but trying to getSkueDetails.

Anyways, does this mean that the official guide Google has out there on how to implement in-app-purchases doesn't work?

I don't get this - there's 1000s of apps out there having in-app-purchases, all those programmers can't have been struggling with getting it to work like this?!

Comment: Hmm, for some odd reason it works now.. I guess that it needs to be in alpha and activates to not come up with this null error.